# Listview not getting populated if another activity is included Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an activity where i have a list view. On top of the list view i include another layout activity which contains two spinners for filtering the list view. But if i include the filters the list view is not working. It is not getting populated. If i remove it the list view is getting populated.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/filter" layout="@layout/activity_expense_list_filter" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/filter"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">                
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if i remove the filter view the list view is working as expected. Any ideas how i can resolve this

Comment: Post another xml code and java code also

Answer (score 0):

What is the layout for `activity_expense_list_filter.xml`?  Does it also contain an element also called `@android:id/list`?

**EDIT:**

I have a feeling that, it being titled "filter", the included layout is completely obscuring your list.  Is it's opacity at 100%?

Comment: no as i said it only contains two spinners. It is a relative layout to position two spinners are top and left and top right. It does not have a list

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was because i have added width and height as match_parent in the other layout. so it is on top of the listview and it is occupying the entire width and height hiding the list view from the view. I set it to wrap_content and got it fixed.